# How can you determine what Sharepoint WebPartZone you are in from an XSL file to dynamically output the style?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, web-parts

I have a page with 5 Sharepoint web part zones and an XML web part that can go in any of them. One of them needs different styling than the other 4. Is it possible to have the XSL file determine what webzone the web part is in and style it appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

But I also don't think it would be right.

If you need a different html in that zone the use another XSL file
If you just need different styling of the same html the put a div with a class around the zone and handle the styling in CSS

Comment: Definitely a better approach. Also, it's not possible.

Comment: Thank you both. I am very new to Sharepoint so I have no idea what's possible yet but I'm trying to learn!